# Open SQLite console and execute SQL without exiting

Tags: bash, sqlite, command-line-interface

For convenience, I want to make a batch file that opens a terminal, runs SQLite and connects to a database, attaches some other database, and leaves the SQLite terminal open.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlite3 -interactive "/db.sqlite" <<EOS
  ATTACH DATABASE "/sb2.sqlite" AS db2;
EOS
```

The problem is that `sqlite3` quits right after executing the command.

Any ideas on how to leave it open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that sqlite3 automatically exits when it gets an EOF from standard input, which it does at the end of the heredoc. Luckily, one of the command line options it takes is `-cmd SQL`, which is evaluated before it starts reading from standard input. So, your script might look something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 -interactive -cmd "ATTACH '/sb2.sqlite' AS db2" /db.sqlite
```

Alternatively, if you always want this run every time you start the `sqlite3` client, you can put it in your `~/.sqliterc` file, or use `-init /path/to/other/file`.